# How to load data if needed ? React / Redux. No SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Is it possible to load data if needed?

**For example:** first time I loaded `list of challenges` then I went to details page. Now I will refresh page and will get errors something like `challenges undefined` because calling `api` only when loading `list of challenges`.

So question is how to call api again only that time when `store` is empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Your higher order component should get the list of challenges, so even if its refreshed it will fetch all the required data. To avoid re-fetching data, check if that value exists in store before hitting API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, but solution's above not what i need.

So i achieved that with `onEnter` hook on `Route`.

Here is my approach:

```
export default function(store, history) {
    const requireChallenges = (nextState) => {
        if(!challengesIsLoaded(store.getState())) {
            store.dispatch(fetchChallenges());
        }
    };
    return (
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={history}>
                <Route path="/challenges/" component={ChallengesScene} onEnter={requireChallenges} />
              </Router>
            </Provider>
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can set your state like this:

```
this.setState({
  challenges :data
});
```

When you navigate to details page then you can pass this as props to child components as:

```
render{
  return(
    <Details challenges={this.state.challenges }/>
  );
}
```

in details component you can access the data as

```
this.props.challenges
```

and store it inside a variable or your component state.
This way you can always retain your data

Answer (score 1):

Just set your initialState's challenges attribute to null and check if the `state.challenges` if defined before calling the API.

For example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {challenges: null}
}
componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.challenges) {
        MyAPI.getChallenges().then(function(result) {
            this.setState({challenges: result.challenge});
        })
    }
}
```